# Declaring a function using auto, decltype, = , [ ]

Tags: c++

I found a function defined this way on:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

I have never seen this syntax used to defined a function, can anyone explain this?
This only seems to work with auto and decltype

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto f = [](int a, int b)->int
{
    return a * b;
};

/*
int f = [](int a, int b)  //DOES NOT WORK
{
    return a * b;
};
*/

int main()
{
    int a = 2, b = 3;
    cout<<f(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not certain if the following function uses dectype when we do:

```
->int
```

If it does, then how?

Comment: `f` is no function, but a lambda

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda Not sure what you're asking about `decltype`

Comment: @Freddy `trailing return type`, actually.. ;)

Comment: Does `int(int,int) f = ...` work?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger, No.  The type of a lambda is implementation defined by the compiler and that syntax you specified is invalid. However, you can use `std::function<int(int,int)> f = ...` and it will be able to convert to that properly.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger, also if there is no capture list, it is convertible to a function pointer: `int(*f)(int,int) = ...` or `typedef int(*f_t)(int,int); f_t f = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
auto f = [](int a, int b)->int
{
    return a * b;
};
```

The `f` here is a global variable of some anonymous type, holding an instance of the anonymous function object defined after the `operator=`. Such anonymous function objects are called *lambda*s, they can occur everywhere where you can have some expression:

```
int main(int, char**) {
  ([](int a) {
    cout << "lambda called with " << a << endl;
  })(42);
  return ([](int a, int b) { return a - 2 * b; })(42, 21);
}
```

The general syntax of such a lambda expression is the following:

```
"["CAPTURE"]" PARAMETERS ["mutable"] [RETURN] { BODY }
```

`CAPTURE` being a list of zero ore more of

- variable from the enclosing scope, capture by value
- variable from the enclosing scope, preceeded by `&`, capture by reference
- `&` means capture all variables from the enclosing scope by reference
- `=` means capture all variables from the enclosing scope by value

`PARAMETERS` are the usual parameter lists you know from functions, optionally (since C++14) with `auto` and type deduction.

`mutable` allows the lambda to mutate its captured variables.

The *optional* `RETURN` contains a specification of the return type, e.g. `-> void` and the `BODY` contains arbitrary expressions and statements.

**Note** that this is only a rough sketch of the syntax, but it should get you started. You can find out more about lambdas in the standard, searching for "C++11 lambda" on Google or for example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Btw, a lambda is nothing spooky, you can think of your `f` as being a rough equivalent of the following, "old style" C++ code:

```
struct {
  int operator()(int a, int b) const {
    return a * b;
  }
} f;
```

Comment: The parenthesis around the lambda is unnecessary and doesn't really add to the clarity of the expression.  `[](int a) {
    cout << "lambda called with " << a << endl;
  }(42);` is adequate.

Comment: I know, I put them there on purpose to make it absolutely clear where the definition of the lambda ends and where the actual call to the lambda starts.

Answer (score 2):

When you use:

```
auto f = [](int a, int b)->int
{
    return a * b;
};
```

the type of `f` is type of the lambda expression. It is not `int`, the return type of the lambda expression.

As far as the `-> int` part goes, that's the only syntax available to explicitly specify the return type of a lambda expression. It that is omitted, the return type is deduced by the compiler using an algorithm specified by the standard:

> **5.1.2 Lambda expressions**
>
> 4 If a *lambda-expression* does not include a *lambda-declarator*, it is as if the *lambda-declarator* were (). If a *lambda-expression* does not include a *trailing-return-type*, it is as if the *trailing-return-type* denotes the
>   following type:
>
> — if the *compound-statement* is of the form
>   `{` *attribute-specifier-seqopt* `return` *expression* `; }`
>
> the type of the returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion(4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
>
> — otherwise, void.
>
> [ *Example:*

```
 auto x1 = [](int i){ return i; }; // OK: return type is int
 auto x2 = []{ return { 1, 2 }; }; // error: the return type is void (a
 // braced-init-list is not an expression)
```

> —*end example* ]